# Problem with rational numbers

Tags: rational-numbers

Let  $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Demonstrate that if the numbers $a = x^3–x$ and $b = x^2 +1$ are rational, then $x$ is rational.

Comment: Any idea, please...

Comment: Any attempt, please...

Comment: Any effort, please...

Comment: amWhy, Why do you say I have to make an effort because I just wrote a solution, did not you see it?

Comment: I just wanted to check my solution, did you understand? amWhy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  $x^3-x=x\bigl((x^2+1)-2\bigr)$

Comment: I'm discussing the 3 cases, x = 1, -1 and x different from 1, -1 then generalize the conclusion?

Comment: @Alexx If you know how to do it, then post a complete answer.

Comment: x^2+1∈ Q, 2∈ Q result (x-1)(x+1)∈Q

Comment: @Alexx Yes, that's true,

Comment: x^3-x ∈ Q result x(x^2-1)∈ Qresult x(x-1)(x-1)∈Q, case 1:x=1,1∈ Q result x∈ Q;case 2:x=-1, -1∈ Q result x∈ Q:case 3:if x diffrent 1 and x diffrent -1: x different 1result x-1 diffrent 0, xdiffrent -1result x+1diffrent 0: Then (x-1)(x+1) diffrent 0.

Comment: x(x-1)(x+1)∈ Q and (x-1)(x+1)∈ Q and (x-1)(x+1) diffrent 0  result x(x-1)(x+1)\(x-1)(x+1) ∈ Q result x∈ Q.

Comment: Because in each possible  cases, x∈ Q result x∈ Q, in any case. Its complete my solution?

Comment: @Alexx What about this: $x=\frac{x^3-x}{x^2+1-2}=\frac a{b-2}\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: a and b are rational so a and b-2 are rational so a/(b-2) is rational if b is'nt 2

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+1\in \mathbb Q \implies x^2\in \mathbb Q$

From this, we deduce that $x^3=rx$ for some $r\in \mathbb Q$. It is easy to see that $r=1\implies x=0,\pm 1$ which are all rational.  Assume, then, that $r\neq 1$.

But this implies that $x^3-x=x(r-1)\in \mathbb Q\implies x\in \mathbb Q$ as desired.